# how to define array of array of objects in java script

Tags: javascript

Which way is the correct way to define array of array of objects below is my javascript code,thanks

```
var A1 = [
      B1 : [
             { Text: 'Home',
               name: "i do not know"
              },
              { Text: 'Taj',
                name: "you may know"
              }
           ],
      B2 : [
             { Text: 'Homeone',
              name: "i do not knows"
               },
              { Text: 'Tasj',
              name: "you may knows"
             }
           ]
          ]
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome do you want to achieve?

Comment: `var A1 = [ {B1: [...]}, {B2: [...]}]` - note, object properties have key values (B1, B2, Text etc) ... array items do not (that is where your code is wrong)

Comment: instead of array do i need to create b1 as object like this "B1" : {

Comment: `var parent = [], arrayOfObjects = [{attr: value}, {a: v}, {a:v }]; parent.push(arrayOfObjects);`

Comment: You can create a parent array and then push your "array of objects"

Comment: or object of array of object to make better

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in doing this?

Comment: Please go read [ask], it explains what the correct way to ask a question is to begin with.

Comment: @cbroe your genius than me

Answer (score 1):

```
var A1 = [
  {B1 : [
         { Text: 'Home',
           name: "i do not know"
          },
          { Text: 'Taj',
            name: "you may know"
          }
       ]},
  {B2 : [
         { Text: 'Homeone',
          name: "i do not knows"
           },
          { Text: 'Tasj',
          name: "you may knows"
         }
       ]}
      ];
```

Please see the code. You should declare your array with object as its properties.

Comment: Didn't get you, What do you wants to do?

Comment: If you wants exactly the same, than yes this is best and simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Array of Array can be defined this way :

```
var A1 = [[
    {
        Text: 'Home',
        name: 'i do not know'
    },
    {
         Text: 'Taj',
         name: 'you may know'
    }
 ], [
    {
        Text: 'Homeone',
        name: 'i do not knows'
    },
    {
        Text: 'Tasj',
        name: 'you may knows'
    }
 ]]
```

Comment: The best way is opinion based, array of array are defined this way, I see alot of people are not defining array of array, but _array_ of objects containing a property that has array as value

Comment: To me the simpler the better

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to define using array literal as below:

```
var myArray = [
                 [{
                     Text:'Home',
                     name: "i do not know"
                   },
                  {
                    Text: 'Taj',
                    name: "you may know"
                  }],
                 [{
                    Text: 'Homeone',
                    name: "i do not knows"
                  },
                  {
                    Text: 'Tasj',
                    name: "you may knows"
                  }]
               ];
```

Or You as per your code you can do other way as well , as below:

**Define/get each object and pass it to array**

Ex:

```
var B1 =  [
         { Text: 'Home',
           name: "i do not know"
          },
          { Text: 'Taj',
            name: "you may know"
          }
       ];
  var B2 = [
         { Text: 'Homeone',
          name: "i do not knows"
           },
          { Text: 'Tasj',
          name: "you may knows"
         }
       ];

   var  A1 = [ B1, B2 ];
```